# Spotify Oauth, Getting users profile

Tags: php, json, curl, oauth, spotify

I'm trying to allow users to login to my site using their spotify account but receive

> {"error":"server_error","error_description":"Unexpected status: 415"}

when receiving the JSON response.

This is the code I'm using:

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])  ) {
    echo $_GET['code'];
    $scode = $_GET['code'];
    $surl2 = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";
    $sdata2=array("grant_type"=>"authorization_code","code"=>$scode,"redirect_uri"=>$sredicturl,"client_id"=>$Sclient,"client_secret"=>$Ssecret);
    $sch2=curl_init($surl2);
    curl_setopt($sch2,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($sch2,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$sdata2);
    curl_setopt($sch2,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    curl_setopt($sch2,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $sjson_response2=curl_exec($sch2);
    curl_close($sch2);
    echo"<br/>".$sjson_response2;
```

I'm at number 4 in the spotify documentation... https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the error is due to the form data being posted as `multipart/form-data` (because you are passing an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`).

Instead, try:

```
curl_setopt($sch2,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($sdata2));
```

This way it POSTs data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.